# Converting from BigQuery to MySQL, variable array size

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I'm translating the below `BigQuery` source to `MySQL`.
The problem is the `GENERATE_ARRAY`, producing a **variable-length array** which is unacceptable for `MySQL`.
I think I need to make a virtual table using `WITH array AS ( ... )`, but It seems not easy because the size of array is not fixed.
Any idea to cope with it?

[The table used looks like this→](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVFV4.png)

```sql
-- This query generates a row for every hour the patient is in the ICU.
-- The hours are based on clock-hours (i.e. 02:00, 03:00).
-- The hour clock starts 24 hours before the first heart rate measurement.
-- Note that the time of the first heart rate measurement is ceilinged to the hour.

-- this query extracts the cohort and every possible hour they were in the ICU
-- this table can be to other tables on ICUSTAY_ID and (ENDTIME - 1 hour,ENDTIME]

-- get first/last measurement time
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS icustay_hourly(
with all_hours as
(
select
  it.stay_id

  -- ceiling the intime to the nearest hour by adding 59 minutes then truncating
  -- note that we truncate by parsing as string, rather than using DATETIME_TRUNC
  -- this is done to enable compatibility with psql
  , PARSE_DATETIME(
      '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00',
      FORMAT_DATETIME(
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00',
          DATE_ADD(it.intime_hr, INTERVAL '59' MINUTE)
  )) AS endtime

  -- create integers for each charttime in hours from admission
  -- so 0 is admission time, 1 is one hour after admission, etc, up to ICU disch
  --  we allow 24 hours before ICU admission (to grab labs before admit)
  , GENERATE_ARRAY(-24, CEIL(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(HOUR, it.outtime_hr, it.intime_hr))) as hrs

  from mimic_derived.icustay_times it
)
SELECT stay_id
, CAST(hr AS BIGINT) as hr
, DATE_ADD(endtime, INTERVAL CAST(hr AS BIGINT) HOUR) as endtime
FROM all_hours
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(all_hours.hrs) AS hr
);
```

Comment: Most of this code just has nothing to do with MySQL.  You should ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.  Your existing code can be useful for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Python and generated the intended table.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
import datetime

com = pymysql.connect(  host=111.111.111.111, 
                        port=3306, 
                        user=root,
                        password=pw, 
                        db="mimic_derived"  )

icustay_times = pd.read_sql_query('select * from icustay_times', com)

icustay_hourly = []
for row in range(len(icustay_times)): # 12 minutes
    intime = icustay_times['intime_hr'][row]
    if pd.isnull(intime): continue # NULL intime_hr & outtime_hr
        
    stay_id = icustay_times['stay_id'][row]
    
    endtime = intime + datetime.timedelta(minutes=59) # DATETIME_ADD
    endtime = endtime - datetime.timedelta(days=1) # a day eariler (starts from -24)

    outtime = icustay_times['outtime_hr'][row]

    dt = outtime - intime.floor('H') # DATETIME_DIFF
    dt_in_hours = dt.components.days*24 + dt.components.hours

    rng = range(-24, dt_in_hours+1) # GENERATE_ARRAY
    for i, hr in enumerate(rng): # CROSS JOIN UNNEST
        icustay_hourly.append([ stay_id,  # DATETIME_ADD
                                hr, 
                                endtime.floor('H') + datetime.timedelta(hours=i)])
        
icustay_hourly = pd.DataFrame(icustay_hourly, columns=('stay_id', 'hr', 'endtime'))
com.close()

# <Create Table>
# pd.read_sql_query('''
# CREATE TABLE icustay_hourly(
#     stay_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
#     hr INT NOT NULL,
#     endtime DATETIME NOT NULL
# )''', com)

# <Case 1>
# data.to_csv('icustay_hourly.csv', index=False)
# pd.read_sql_query('''
# LOAD DATA INFILE 'icustay_hourly.csv' INTO TABLE emp
# FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS
# ''', com)

# <Case 2)>
# for row in range(len(icustay_times)): # 40 minutes
#     query = f'''
#     INSERT INTO icustay_hourly (stay_id, hr, endtime) 
#     VALUES (
#         {icustay_times['stay_id'][row]}, 
#         {icustay_times['hr'][row]}, 
#         {icustay_times['endtime'][row]}
#     )'''
#     try:
#         pd.read_sql_query(query, com)
#     except TypeError: # pd.read_sql_query requires return
#         pass:
```